# Driver Load error in Non Admin user account

Tags: c++, device-driver

I have written a driver, it works fine in Administrator account on Win XP. But my final product is to run on non admin account. I am running it on non admin account for testing. But driver is not able to load.
CreateFile() function returns error no 6. which means INVALID_HANDLE.
Please reply ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load new drivers as a non-administrator on Windows XP.